# in PHP development, is there anything like rspec in Rails?

Tags: php, tdd

I am wondering in PHP development, what kind of TDD tool is popular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+tdd

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test Driven Development in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276/test-driven-development-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular equivalent I am aware of is [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).

Answer (score 0):

another one is [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/).

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312/simple-test-vs-phpunit) is a thread "Simple test vs PHPunit"